# Add unique sparse index to an existing database

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a database and now I want to add a unique and sparse index to my existing collection. The problem is that I'm getting this error from MongoDB:

```
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: dbname.posts.$ref.origin_1_user_1  dup key: { : null, : ObjectId('54df4f8f93a640bd16000001') }",
        "code" : 11000
}
```

As far as I know, `sparse` index is used for columns that might have null values, so that's the reason I used `sparse` option:

```
db.posts.ensureIndex({ "ref.origin": 1, "user": 1 },  {  unique: true, sparse: true })
```

What's the problem with my `createIndex` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if the 2-tuple `('ref.origin', 'user')` isn't unique, you got a unique key violation. In this case, the tuple's value is `{ null,  ObjectId('54df4f8f93a640bd16000001') }`.

The fact that the index is sparse will matter [only if the *entire set of fields* is absent](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-and-unique-properties), i.e. even `{ null, null }` tuples won't be ignored, but their uniqueness is ensured. Both fields, i.e. both `ref.origin` and `user` must be unset for this to work.

Comment: So what should I do in this situation?

Comment: That depends on what you need to do, exactly. Which queries do you need?

Comment: Thanks, I changed my data structure and now `sparse` works well.